# How to find out what larger package some command is included in?

Tags: package-management

I recently had a problem, and the good people on the interwebz seemed to agree that I should run the command "cec-client".

```
$ cec-client
-bash: cec-client: command not found
$ sudo apt-get install cec-client
E: Couldn't find package cec-client
```

At this point I had to google some more, finding out that cec-client was part of something called libcec, and that I should git clone and compile this library. Even for a semi-noob like me, this seemed rather convoluted, and lots of errors ensued.

Only later did I find out that cec-client is part of something called cec-utils, which I could install with sudo apt-get install.

I wasted a few hours on this. I assume that there is an established method by which I should have been able to discover that I needed to install cec-utils.

So what is it?

Best regards,
Steen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either search the online catalog at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

[image: packages.ubuntu.com search]

or install and use the `apt-file` utility:

```
$ apt-file search cec-client
cec-utils: /usr/bin/cec-client
cec-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/cec-client.1.gz
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really solves a lot of problems for me! :-)